# How can I store URLs from Amazon S3 bucket in Django sqlite db to display & comment on?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I've been using Django for a couple of days & setup a basic blog from a [tutorial](http://brenelz.com/blog/a-detailed-django-tutorial-blog-basics-part-iii/#base) with django comments.

I've got a totally separate python script that generates screenshots and uploads them to Amazon S3, now I'd like my django app to display all the images in the bucket and use a comment system on the images. Preferably I'd do this by just storing the URLs in my sqlite db, which I've got hard-coded currently to display all images in the db and has comments enabled on these.

My model:

(Does this need a foreign key to the django comments or is that just part of the Django Magic?!)

```
class Image(models.Model):
imgUrl=models.CharField(max_length=200)
meta=models.CharField(max_length=300)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.imgUrl
```

My bucket structure:
`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/revision/process/images.png`

Almost all the tutorials and packages I'm finding are based on upload/download rather than a simple `for keys in bucket` type approach that I want.

One of my problems is understanding how I can integrate my Boto functions with Django if I'm using Base.html. In an earlier tutorial I had an index page which had a view and could call functions from there. But base doesn't need that so I'm starting to get a little lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haven't looked up if boto api changed, but this is how it worked last time i looked

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import s3config

conn    = S3Connection(s3config.passwd, s3config.secret)
bucket  = conn.get_bucket(s3config.bucket)
s3_path = '/some/path/in/your/bucket'
keys    = bucket.list(s3_path)
# or if you want all keys:
# keys   = bucket.get_all_keys()

for key in keys:
  print key
  # here you can download or do other stuff
  # with the keys like get some metadata
  print key.name
  print key.etag
  print key.size
  print key.last_modified
```

---

```
#s3config.py
passwd = 'BLABALBALABALA'
secret = 'xvdwv3efefefefefef'
bucket = 'name-of-your-bucket'
```

---

**Update:**

Amazon s3 is a key value store, where key is a string. So nothing prevents you from putting in keys like:

```
/this/string/key/looks/like/a/unix/path
/folder/images/fileA.jpg
/folder/images/fileB.jpg
/folder/images/folderX/fileX1.jpg
```

now `bucket.list(prefix="/folder/images/")` would yield the latter three.
Look here for further details:

- http://readthedocs.org/docs/boto/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto-s3-bucket
- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html?r=8270

Comment: Great thanks. Now I suppose I need to figure out some regex to separate that key.name in to the folders so I can build some organisation in to bucket browsing rather than just a huge list of images.

Comment: well, if remember correctly you can just use the bucket.list(s3_path) function if you like to organize your files in a "unix path like" manner, because it lists all keys having this start string in common.

Comment: http://readthedocs.org/docs/boto/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto-s3-bucket look at the "list()" function's parameters (i.e. prefix, etc..)

Comment: Thank You. Boto is turning out to be great. Now I just need to keep reading the Djangobook to figure out how to store this info.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to store result from s3 to mysql by boto, django.

```
from demo.models import Movies
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import string
from django.db import connection, transaction

def movietitle(b):
    key = b.get_key('netflix/movie_titles.txt')
    content = key.get_contents_as_string()
    line = content.split('\n')
    args = []
    for imovie in line:
        if len(imovie) > 0:
            imovie = imovie.split(',')
            movieid = imovie[0]
            year = imovie[1]
            title = imovie[2]
            iargs = [string.atoi(movieid),title,year]
            args.append(iargs)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "insert into demo_movies(MovieID,MovieName,ReleaseYear) values(%s,%s,%s)"
    cursor.executemany(sql,args)
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
    cursor.close()
```